# What does memory dump feature in WP8.1 apply to? (Debug feedback)

Tags: apps, settings, 8.1-update-1, security, usb

There is a feature in "Settings/feedback/Save debug info" option in the phone settings:

[image: Debug info setting]

If I turn this on, and I start a custom developed application that let's say crashes at some point, the phone will take a snapshot of the memory, and will write it to "\MyPhone\Phone\Documents\Debug\fooBar.dmp" on the phone. By connecting the phone to my PC via USB, I can access these memory dumps, which is a risk from a security perspective.

My question is, **is this behavior true for non developer unlocked phones too? Do you think it's a security issue too?**

Comment: Dev questions belong on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Thomas I edited it, please consider reopening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option doesn't show for phones that are not developer unlocked.

Even when they do exist on a (developer unlocked) phone, which can give you information about what was in the process's memory at the time of the dump - there is a risk that sensitive information that application had could be leaked, but it would only be leaked to the phone's owner (who arguably had that information already)